# Proof of Engel’s theorem on Wikipedia

Tags: proof-explanation, lie-algebras

According to this page on Engel’s theorem on [Wikipedia]
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel%27s_theorem#Proof)

> Write $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} + L
> $ where $L$ is a one-dimensional vector subspace. Let $Y$ be a nonzero vector in $L$ and $ 
> v $ a nonzero vector in $W$. Now, Y is a nilpotent endomorphism (by hypothesis) and so $Y^k(v) \neq 0, Y^{k+1}(v) = 0 $for some $k$. Then $Y^k(v)$ is a required vector as the vector lies in $W$ by Step 2. $\square $

But I cannot see anywhere on that page where we can say that $W$ contains a nonzero vector.

Any help here?

Comment: Do you have a text on Lie algebras? I think it would be helpful, because you are asking for the standard results, which usually are proved in detail, e.g., in the book by Erdmann and Wildon.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is by induction on the dimension of $\mathfrak{g}$.  So the induction hypothesis tells you that the desired result already holds for $\mathfrak{h}$, which exactly says that $W$ contains a nonzero vector.